# Lifetime = -1; does not effect Unity particles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, particle-system

I found a lot of topics saying that if I would like to remove a specific particle, I simply have to set it's `LifeTime` to `-1`.

I know my loop is working correctly, as the movement of each particle goes as planned AND I can see the "remove particle" Debug line in my log the moment it reaches it's destination. Did anything change over time, or am I missing something simple?

I'm using Unity 5,4,3f1 Personal

```
void Update ()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) PlayParticleEffect();

    if (particleSystem != null) {           
        particles = new ParticleSystem.Particle[particleSystem.particleCount];
        int count = particleSystem.GetParticles (particles);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            ParticleSystem.Particle particle = particles [i];
            float dist = Vector3.Distance (particleTarget.transform.position, particle.position);
            if (dist > 0.1f) {
                particle.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (particle.position, particleTarget.transform.position, Time.deltaTime * 10);
                particles [i] = particle;
            } else {
                particle.lifetime = -0;
                Debug.Log ("remove particle");
            }
        }
        particleSystem.SetParticles (particles, count);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're setting it to zero, not -1

Comment: Yeah, I tried a couple of things I read about in different topics, but without succes. This was my last try before turning to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the remaining lifetime of the particle to 0 (if it's set to 0, the particle will disappear).

Your code doesn't work because you forgot to add `particles [i] = particle;` in the else branch of your if, you're never setting the lifetime to 0 to the actual particle:

```
if (dist > 0.1f) {
    particle.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (particle.position, Vector3.zero, Time.deltaTime * 10);
    particles [i] = particle;
} else {
    particle.remainingLifetime = 0;
    particles [i] = particle;       
}
```

P.S.: I used `remainingLifetime` instead of `lifetime` since I'm on Unity 5.5

Comment: Ah yes, now I see! I hate it when it is something simple as that haha. Thanks allot man!

Comment: No worries, it happened to me a lot of times too!